# How to draw several arcs in an svg circle according to each arc percentage?

Tags: svg, automatic-ref-counting, donut-chart

I need to represent something like a donut chart in SVG.
I was trying to draw several arcs inside the same circle, each one with the length defined by a percentage that is previously givven. But with no luck...

Here is a pic:

[image]

What I need is that every region will be dynamically defined according to a percentage previously established.

Does anyone knows how can this be done?

Comment: use the elliptical arc command of a path element.

Comment: You are right @AlexanderV.Ulyanov, done, pic added. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I've used to resolve a similar situation:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" width="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
  <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />
  <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" stroke="green" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="calc(60 * 31.42 / 100) 31.42" transform="rotate(-90) translate(-20)" />
  <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="calc(40 * 31.42 / 100) 31.42" transform="rotate(-90) translate(-20)" />
  <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" stroke-width="10" fill="white" />
</svg>
```

To calculate percentages You need to calculate the percentage for the last circle "yellow" and then for the second circle "green" you have to calculate the percentage and sum the yellow circle percentage.

Example:

- Yellow -> 20% -> calc(**20** * 31.42 / 100) 31.42
- Green  -> 30% -> calc(**50** * 31.42 / 100) 31.42 (50 = 20(yellow) + 30(green))

Answer (score 2):

@user1835591 What do you think about it?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="transform-origin:50% 50%;transform:rotate(270deg)" stroke-width="8%" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="400%">
 <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" stroke="#ff8c00"/>
 <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" stroke-dashoffset="284%" stroke="#7fffd4"/>
 <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" stroke-dashoffset="318%" stroke="#228b22"/>
 <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" stroke-dashoffset="352%" stroke="#6495ed"/>
 <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" stroke-dashoffset="376%" stroke="#4169e1"/>
 <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" stroke-dashoffset="390%" stroke="#ffa500"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: It might work, I just dont get how the stroke-dashoffset works? What range is it? if its percentage, shouldnt it be from 0-100?

Comment: Also, why do I get a yellow part larger than all others if I do a fill=white? [link to picture](https://imgur.com/a/67wHYvn) this is the code i'm using: `<svg xmlns="w3.org/2000/svg" style="transform-origin:50% 50%;transform:rotate(270deg)" stroke-width="8%" fill="white" stroke-dasharray="400%"> <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" stroke-width="10" stroke="red"/> <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="268%" stroke="green"/> <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="372%" stroke="yellow"/> </svg>`

Comment: @user1835591 dashoffset calculate with radius (atttribute r) r=25% it 1/4 of 100% because 100%*4=400%. Dashoffset default=400%. If you need calculate some part for 30% then 400%-30%=270%. Yellow part larger than other because it layer, its normal. Maybe animate this parts?

Comment: Try it:
<svg xmlns="www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="transform-origin:50% 50%;transform:rotate(270deg)" stroke-width="10%" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="400%">
<circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" stroke="red" fill="white"/>
<circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" stroke-dashoffset="268%" stroke="green"/>
<circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" stroke-dashoffset="372%" stroke="yellow"/>
</svg>

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that as well:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
interface PieProps {
  percentage: number,
  segmentColor: string,
}

const elements: PieProps[] = [
  { percentage: 10, segmentColor: 'red' },
  { percentage: 35, segmentColor: 'blue' },
  { percentage: 25, segmentColor: 'green' },
  { percentage: 30, segmentColor: 'black' },
];

const radius = 14;
const roundCircum = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
const strokeWidth = 3;

const offsets = computed(() => {
  const offset: number[] = [0];
  elements.map((value) => offset.push(offset[offset.length - 1] + ((value.percentage) * roundCircum) / 100));
  return offset;
});
</script>

<template>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <circle
      v-for="(element, index) in elements"
      :key="element.segmentColor"
      :r="radius"
      cx="50%"
      cy="50%"
      :stroke="element.segmentColor"
      :stroke-dasharray="`${((element.percentage) * roundCircum) / 100}, ${roundCircum}`"
      :stroke-dashoffset="-offsets[index]"
      fill="none"
      :stroke-width="strokeWidth"
    />
  </svg>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

[svg arcs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#arcs) look like another option, they are the "A" segments of the path below. "M" moves to the start position, "A" defined the radius, some flags and the end position.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="100" height="100"
   version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="
        M 50 10
        A 40 40 0 0 1 69.270  14.948 "
    fill="none" stroke="bisque" stroke-width="15" />
  <path d=" M 69.270 14.948 A 40 40 0 0 1 85.052 30.730"
    fill="none" stroke="steelblue" stroke-width="15" />
  <path d=" M 85.052 30.730 A 40 40 0 0 1 85.052 69.270"
    fill="none" stroke="skyblue" stroke-width="15" />
  <path d=" M 85.052 69.270 A 40 40 0 0 1 44.987 89.685"
    fill="none" stroke="forestgreen" stroke-width="15" />
  <path d=" M 44.987 89.685 A 40 40 0 0 1 10.079 52.512"
    fill="none" stroke="lightgreen" stroke-width="15" />
  <path d=" M 10.079 52.512 A 40 40 0 0 1 50.000 10.000"
    fill="none" stroke="orange" stroke-width="15" />
</svg>
```

The `large-arc-flag` would need to be set for >50% arcs (3rd number after "A")

The quick-and-dirty percent to arc endpoint code I used:

```
perl -e '$pi=atan2(0,-1);$r=40;$c=50;' \
 -e 'for(@ARGV) {$a+=$_*2*$pi/100; printf "$_ %.03f %.03f\n", $c+$r*sin($a),$c+$r*-cos($a)}' \
8 9 16 19 22 26 # percentages clockwise
```